# How to check docker logs along with datetime?

Tags: docker

Using docker, is there a way when checking logs with

```
docker logs --tail=50  project-composer
```

to also show the datetime when these logs were printed?
I mean, for logs which don't already contain any datetime in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the `docker logs` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/), you can use the `-t` option:

> `--timestamps , -t`: Show timestamps

```
docker logs --tail=50 -t project-composer
```

For completeness, here is an example session with a toy while loop:

```
$ docker run -d --rm --name=background debian /bin/bash -c \
    'while true; do echo $SECONDS; sleep 1s; done'
$ sleep 10s; docker logs -t background

2020-09-05T12:30:56.013080385Z 0
2020-09-05T12:30:57.014457565Z 1
2020-09-05T12:30:58.015937946Z 2
2020-09-05T12:30:59.017549558Z 3
2020-09-05T12:31:00.020069215Z 4
2020-09-05T12:31:01.022548109Z 5
2020-09-05T12:31:02.025173529Z 6
2020-09-05T12:31:03.027763759Z 7
2020-09-05T12:31:04.030268712Z 8
2020-09-05T12:31:05.032830663Z 9
2020-09-05T12:31:06.035314712Z 10

$ docker kill background
```